# Pass multiple args to thread using struct (pthread)

Tags: struct, pthreads

I'm learning to programming using pthread for a adder program, after reference several codes still don't get how to pass multiple arguments into a thread using a struct, here is my buggy program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct s_addition {
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int sum;
} addition;


void *thread_add_function (void *ad)
{
    printf ("ad.num1:%d, ad.num2:%d\n",ad.num1, ad.num2);

    ad.sum = ad.num1 + ad.num2;
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main()
{
    int N = 5;
    int a[N], b[N], c[N];
    srand (time(NULL));
    // fill them with random numbers
    for ( int j = 0; j < N; j++ ) {
        a[j] = rand() % 392;
        b[j] = rand() % 321;        
    }

    addition ad1;
    pthread_t thread[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        ad1.num1 = a[i];
        ad1.num2 = b[i];
        printf ("ad1.num1:%d, ad1.num2:%d\n",ad1.num1, ad1.num2);
        pthread_create (&thread[i], NULL, thread_add_function, &ad1);
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
        c[i] = ad.sum;
    }

    printf( "This is the result of using pthread.\n");
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf( "%d + %d = %d\n", a[i], b[i], c[i]);
    }
}
```

But when compiling I got the following error:

> vecadd_parallel.c:15:39: error: member reference base type 'void *' is not a
>         structure or union
>           printf ("ad.num1:%d, ad.num2:%d\n",ad.num1, ad.num2);

I tried but still cannot get a clue, what I am doing wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have a problem with trying to access the members of a void datatype.

You will need to add a line to cast your parameter to `thread_add_function` to the correct datatype similar to `addition* add = (addition*)ad;`, and then use this variable in your function (note that you also have to change you r `.`'s to `->` because it's a pointer)

You also should only pass data to threads that was `malloc()`'d, as stack allocated data may not be permanent. It should be fine for the current implementation, but changes later could easily give strange, unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, I finally find the problem! But I don't fully understand your second suggestion, I am wondering how I can malloc a thread, would you please point me to some references?

Comment: It was just a small piece of advice. You shouldn't pass the location of data on the stack to the last parameter of `pthread_create` because this data could be reused or have undefined value if say this was inside a function, and it returned. You shouldn't have a problem with the current code, because all your threads finish before the main function returns, and your program exits when it does anyway.